# How Can Use react Router?

Tags: reactjs

i have an app component where map over my data an return a component, I want to make app the homepage that displays the component i return

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import data from "./data";
import Asteriods from "./components/Asteroids";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Header from "./components/Header";

import "./App.css";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    // calculations: [],
    asteroids: data,
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="space">
        <Header />

        {this.state.asteroids.map((item) => (
          <Asteriods key={item.id} item={item} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

I also have a component that where i want to link to that other component and still pass props to the stock component

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
import Stock from "./Stock";

class AsteroidDetails extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="popup">
        <div className="popup\_inner">
          <button onClick={this.props.closePopup}>X</button>

          <p> - Name: {this.props.asteroid.name}</p>
          <p> - Type: {this.props.asteroid.type}</p>
          <p> - Mass: {this.props.asteroid.mass}</p>

          <a href="#">Link to vieuw stock</a>

          <Stock
            // chemPerDay={this.props.chemPerDay}
            {...this.props}
            // remainingMassPerday={this.props.remainingMassPerday}
            // asteroidYieldPerDay={this.props.asteroidYieldPerDay}
            // remainingMpct={this.props.remainingMpct}
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default AsteroidDetails;
```

how can i use react router in both of these cases ?

Comment: use `Link` component of `react-router`, do not use `a` tag

Comment: yeah, i know, i just put it there temporarily until i know who to use react-router

Comment: You need to setup router. You can find many examples at https://reactrouter.com/web/example/basic